# Trying to change image source with Javascript, not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm including the Javascript (jQuery really) in order to change the img src in question from one image to another image on hover.

However this isn't working - the images don't change at all.

My only guess is that the unnamed functions aren't doing what I want them to do.

My knowledge of jQuery is still somewhat new, so I'm stumped here and can't find any resources on what I might be doing wrong.

```
jQuery("#fbicon").hover(
function () {
    jQuery(this).attr("src","images/nohoverfb.png");
},
function () {
    jQuery(this).attr("src","images/fb.png");
});

jQuery("#linkedinicon").hover(
function () {
    jQuery(this).attr("src","images/nohoverlinkedin.png");
},
function () {
    jQuery(this).attr("src","images/linkedin.png");
});

jQuery("#googleplusicon").hover(
function () {
    jQuery(this).attr("src","images/nohovergoogle+.png");
},
function () {
    jQuery(this).attr("src","images/google+.png");
});

jQuery("#youtubeicon").hover(
function () {
    jQuery(this).attr("src","images/nohoveryoutube.png");
},
function () {
    jQuery(this).attr("src","images/youtube.png");
});

jQuery("#twittericon").hover(
function () {
    jQuery(this).attr("src","images/nohovertwitter.png");
},
function () {
    jQuery(this).attr("src","images/twitter.png");
});

jQuery("#emailicon").hover(
function () {
    jQuery(this).attr("src","images/nohoveremail.png");
},
function () {
    jQuery(this).attr("src","images/email.png");
});
```

Here is an example of the HTML:

```
<span class="icon"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/facebookname"><img id="fbicon" src="http://www.website.com/sites/all/themes/website/images/fb.png" style="height:48px;width:48px"></a></span>
```

Comment: Hey, your function call seems correct. You can see network log if your hover image is geting downloaded or not as it may take some time. You may try with placehold images like "http://placehold.it/100x100"...

Answer (score 1):

I think you are making a mistake in order of functions:

Try this:

```
$("#fbicon").hover(
    function () {
        jQuery(this).attr("src","images/fb.png");  //hover in function
    },
    function () {
        jQuery(this).attr("src","images/nohoverfb.png");  //hover out function
    });
```

Change all images accordingly in your code, and that should do what you want it to.

[See the demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6fyeS/28/) which changes background css to red on hover and blue when mouse leaves that div.

Hope it helps.

**EDIT**

I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6fyeS/33/), with your html, which uses 2 images from internet. See that images are changed in Hover in, Hover out.

HTML:

```
<span class="icon"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/facebookname"><img id="fbicon" src="http://s2.reutersmedia.net/resources/r/?m=02&d=20141020&t=2&i=985015946&w=580&fh=&fw=&ll=&pl=&r=LYNXNPEA9J0XH" style="height:48px;width:48px"></a></span>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#fbicon").hover(
    function () {
        jQuery(this).attr("src","http://www.gizbot.com/img/2014/10/14-1413281227-sonyxperiaz3cropedimages600x450withwatermark3.jpg");  //hover in function
    },
    function () {
        jQuery(this).attr("src","http://s2.reutersmedia.net/resources/r/?m=02&d=20141020&t=2&i=985015946&w=580&fh=&fw=&ll=&pl=&r=LYNXNPEA9J0XH");  //hover out function
    });
```

Comment: That is working on the fiddle, but not on live... that's surprising.

Comment: @AndrewAlexander try to put alert in those function. Do alerts work?

Comment: @AndrewAlexander Check if path is correct. See in console for any image not found error if that's case. Is image on `images/nohoverfb.png` location?

Comment: I can even switch the position manually using firebug or chrome's web tools to the other image, and it works fine.

Comment: That's strange. no other errors in console? and did you interchange the images' i functions?

Comment: The image names don't need to be changed. The image is named incorrectly, the images entitled, "nohover" should in fact all just say hover.

I'm getting a bunch of warnings, but those seem to be from Google Analytics. No errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63394/discussion-between-mysticmagic-and-andrew-alexander).